How to convert unused 3 prong, 250V, 50A, F receptacle to regular 120V one?
I have an unused 3 prong, 250V, 50A, F receptacle in my basement.
Is there an adapter out there that can convert this to 120V?
Since it is 3 wire (including neutral), I believe we should be able to do this without a need for a transformer or rewiring from the panel.


If three wire(including neutral) but no ground, then no.  Most 120 volt receptacles will not fit 50 amp wire.  You will also need to change the breaker to 20 or 15 amp.  120v requires one hot, one neutral, and one ground is nice.  250(240) is two hots with ground as a safety, maybe neutral.

Two hots and a neutral, circuits were banned in 96.  If from before 96 they are allowed if not changed.

The cable feeding that outlet looks very old.  If it's cloth or rubber insulation, possibly degraded, and if it's in an unfinished basement and your electric panel is also in the basement, the cost and effort of running new cable is justified.  If running new cable is impractical and the old cable is in good shape, it should be possible to do what you want.

That looks like a  NEMA 10-50, which is an obsolete receptacle type for 120V/240V that has two hot wires and neutral but no ground. But an adapter wouldn't make sense anyway. What makes sense is to reuse the cable. So the question then is: what kind of cable?
A 3-wire cable will typically be one of:

Black/White/Bare - that's what you normally see for either a 120V (black hot, white neutral, bare ground) or 240V receptacle (black hot, white marked to use as hot, bare ground)
Black/Red/Bare - this is used in some places for a 240V receptacle (black and red hot, bare ground)

However, in ye olden times there were circuits without ground. Those are legal if they are unchanged. In your case, you are changing the circuit, so no longer legal. A common type of cable for that was black hot, white hot, bare neutral. A bare neutral can be reused as a bare ground. On the other hand, if it is black hot, red hot, white neutral then you can't use it for a modern 120V grounded circuit.
So turn off the circuit and take off the receptacle cover and see what you've got. If it is:

Black, white, bare - OK for 120V
Black, red, bare - OK for 240V
Black, red, white - Not OK for any modern circuit
Black, red, white, bare - OK for 120V, 240V or 120V/240V

The final issue is wire size. A typical 120V 15A or 20A receptacle probably can't use wires larger than 12 AWG or possibly 10 AWG. A proper 50A cable will typically have 6 AWG wires. But that can be resolved by pigtailing with the appropriate size wire nuts.

It can also be "black, black (maybe with a stripe), bare", which is also fine for reuse as a hot-neutral-ground circuit.  They'll also need to change the breaker out if they do convert the receptacle

@ThreePhaseEel How can black/black/bare be used as hot/neutral/ground? According to https://www.ecmweb.com/national-electrical-code/qa/article/21153538/code-qa-neutral-conductor-identification-requirements non-white wires in a cable can't be used as neutral except 4 AWG or larger. A 50A cable will normally have 6 AWG wires. So unless it is oversized, I don't see how that would work.

Black/stripe/bare definitely works, for a black/black/bare cable you'd be stuck with white tape to designate the neutral (an AHJ would have to be quite picky to reject that in a retrofit situation)

338.10 is the rule that allows the bare UF cable neutral to be used as a ground.  In fact, since post-1996 installations do not allow ungrounded circuits, this conversion is mandatory when using UF.

That is a NEMA10 receptacle allowed only as grandfathered by NEC 250.140. You may find an imported, non-listed device to do that, but it would not be safe.
If installed per code there is no direct quick-swap method to convert to grounded 120v, but experience shows either inspectors were very lenient in interpretation of the NEC or installations were later done improperly. So you need to open the receptacle, verify what you have and go from there.
NEMA10's are designated hot/hot/neutral, so if installed properly to Code that NM cable would be two insulated non-reserved colors (meaning not white or green) and one  white. That provides no wire allowed to be used as or re-identified as green or bare equipment ground.
So your options are:
(1) Leave it ungrounded by replacing with another non-grounding two wire receptacle, replace with a Ground Fault receptacle, or fed by other GFCI receptacle/device, or
(2) Add a ground wire to an acceptable location, or
(3) Replace the cable.
